# User And Admin Auth attempt conflicts with each other

Tags: php, laravel

at first sorry for my bad English
I have created Auth::atempt in UserController for my user login and register to my website
and I have created another Auth:attempt in AdminController to login to Admin panel to add or edit something in website.

when i want to log in to admin panel i enter an admin username and password in login form to log in to panel but it says username or password is wrong .
but when i enter a user's username and password it successfully logs in admin panel
currently i'm using laravel 8

Comment: Can you show us some code? It is pretty difficult to contribute anything without seeing code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a multi authentication system in laravel.
There is the Guards concept.
laravel authentication system uses the default guards mentioned under **config/auth.php** directory

you must register a provider and guard for your admin panel.
Registering Guards

```
'guards' => [
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admin',
        ],
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
]
```

Registering Provider

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],
]
```

after registering your providers and guards. create a separate login controller for your admin as bellow

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminLoginController extends Controller 
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected string $guard = 'admin';

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
    }

    public function guard() 
    {
        return Auth::guard($this->guard);
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        // view for admin login
    }

    public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        // redirect after authentication
    }

    public function loggedOut() 
    {
        // redirect after logout
    }
}
```